# Varnish Cache-Control: Max_Age 0 ; On Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

So I have installed **xVarnish** or, **CacheWall**, but the **Cache-control** `max_age` is set to **0**. I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489796/varnish-appears-to-be-working-but-max-age-0) but I am not sure of the exact location that I can implement the answers suggestion of

"You are just missing `session_cache_limiter` and `session_cache_expire`, which should be the first lines executed on the requested PHP script, even before `session_start()`."

The same person edited their answer to also give the added option of modifying Apache `mod_expires` which I tried to do with this tutorial [here](http://linuxpitstop.com/configure-apache-mod_expires-on-file-extensions/) which  threw an error of wrong syntax when I tried to restart my apache2 server.

Is there a tutorial some one could point me too? or some direction on modifying the `session_start` in magento?

Sorry if this has been asked before and for my noobness. The url I am trying this on is [www.brotomic.com](http://www.brotomic.com) the headers contain

```
 [root@host ~]# curl -I http://www.brotomic.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 18:14:15 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 18:14:15 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=o3h5m3r4ei5o3628ij49940u62; expires=Thu, 17-Aug-2017 19:14:15 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.brotomic.com; HttpOnly
Location: http://brotomic.com/?SID=o3h5m3r4ei5o3628ij49940u62
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 229728
Age: 0
X-Cache: MISS
Connection: keep-alive
```

We are running on a dedicated server and also with `centOS/cpanel`.
Also would a **VCL** file change be appropriate for this?

Thanks.

Comment: The page you are visiting might be uncacheable http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-over.html#config-cache-over-cacheable

Comment: From the link and documentation the only the checkout pages should be uncacheable not the home page or product pages.?

Comment: It might be caused by a third party module.

Comment: are you talking about a module on the backend? What would I be looking for ?

Comment: Start by searching cacheable="false" in your xmls and see which ones are in use.

Comment: @mbalpard Searching the .xml of my revealed that the 'cacheable="false"' value seems to be set on the correct page such as pages dealing with customer data. Searching the .php files returned substantially less instances of the false value but one was interesting in that it occurred in `vender/magneto/framework/View/Layout.php` and stated `$cacheableXml = !(bool)count($this->getXml()->xpath('//' . Element::TYPE_BLOCK . '[@cacheable="false"]'));` not sure it this is correct but seems to be at first glance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the `session_cache_limiter` and `session_cache_expire` through the WHM dashboard in  MultiPHP INI Editor which allowed me to change the settings of these 2 features which changed my header and allowed Varnish to be be enabled.